# Rendering problems (AppCompat 22.1.0)

Tags: android, android-studio, rendering, android-appcompat, preview

I am getting this issue:
[image: image1]

The app works fine, but I can preview nothing in Android Studio...

This is my gradle:
[image: image2]

Comment: Try changing the target revision level at the top of the preview area. That worked for me. I can't get previews for revision level 22, but I can for earlier Android versions.

Comment: @niqueco I tried, but it doesnt work (v21, and v20).

Comment: Oh. Well... I've reported this earlier, they think they have provided a work around, but it didn't work for me. Here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=163275

Comment: Mmm I would like to try it, but I don't know how to clear that cache...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the new version of Android Studio has more problems with folders name. This project was working in version before but now, for example, in a folder called "New Folder", is not working, but in a folder called "NewFolder", is working.

I am only having this problem with a project, all of other projects were in the same folder without problems.

Answer (score 0):

Experienced the same issue with AppCompatActivity, solved it by deleting ***C:\Users\[USER_NAME]\.AndroidStudioPreview1.2\system\caches*** or ***C:\Users\[USER_NAME]\.AndroidStudio\system\caches*** depending on the version of Android Studio being used

Comment: It is not workinf for me, I deleted two times both caches (AndroidStudio and AndroidStudioPreview1.2)

Comment: @Dahnark try **Tools --> Android --> Sync Project with Gradle Files** and  **Build --> Rebuild Project**

Comment: nothimg, I tried this yesterday a lot of times... I tried this too after I deleted caches, but it is not working.

Comment: This is how I solved a similar issue, if it doesn't work for you then I've got nothing. Sorry man :-/

Comment: btw thank you, I opened a new issue on Android forums... if they give me the reply, I come back here to post it.

Comment: @Dahnark this is a _long_ shot, but try fiddle with the preview's rendering API version (the little green bot at the top of the preview window)